# styler R package does nothing

Tags: r, rstudio, r-styler

I've installed the styler package and the function styler:::style_active_file() does nothing.

This is what I've tried and none of these have got it working:

- running styler::cache_clear()
- restarting RStudio
- restarting computer
- reinstalling package

Anyone know why running styler:::style_active_file() does nothing?

Comment: does the Rstudio addin work?

Comment: https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues/648

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: The advice in https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues/648 seems to be restarting RStudio, which I have tried and it still didn't work. It also does not work when running it via RStudio adding.

Comment: You are not supposed to call `styler:::style_active_file()` from the console, as this requires some {rstudioapi} context that is only set when triggering the function via the [RStudio Addin](https://github.com/rstudio/addinexamples). So to style the active file, you should use the RStudio Addin the way its demonstrated in the [README](https://github.com/r-lib/styler).